# keras pre-processing of text using one_hot class

Tags: keras

I came across this code while learning keras online.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

text = 'One hot encoding in Keras'
tokens = text_to_word_sequence(text)
length = len(tokens)
one_hot(text, length)
```

This returns the intergers like this...

> [3, 1, 1, 2, 3]

I did not understand why and how does unique words return duplicate numbers. For e.g. 3 and 1 is repeated even if the words in the text are unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation of `one_hot` it is described how it is a wrapper of `hashing_trick`:

> This is a wrapper to the `hashing_trick` function using hash as the hashing function; unicity of word to index mapping non-guaranteed.

From the documentation of `hasing_trick`:

> Two or more words may be assigned to the same index, due to possible collisions by the hashing function. The probability of a collision is in relation to the dimension of the hashing space and the number of distinct objects.

Since hashing is used there is a probability that different words will be hashed to the same index. The probability of a non-unique hash is proportional to the vocabulary size selected.
It is suggested by Jason Brownlee [Jason Brownlee](https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-text-data-deep-learning-keras/) to use a vocabulary size 25% larger than the word size to increase the uniqueness of the hashes.

Following Jason Brownlee suggestion in you case results in:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence
from tensorflow.random import set_random_seed
import math

set_random_seed(1)
text = 'One hot encoding in Keras'
tokens = text_to_word_sequence(text)
length = len(tokens)
print(one_hot(text, math.ceil(length*1.25)))
```

which returns the integers

> [3, 4, 5, 1, 6]